# Exclude unmatched postal codes in Tableau

Tags: join, tableau-api

I have two tables First is called "All postal codes" and 2nd is called the "Office_Location_Postal_Codes". How do I use these tables to get Postal Codes from First Table which are not in 2nd table?
I tried to leave join, but I think it won't get the correct result. What should I do to get the unmatched postal codes from "All postal codes" Table.

Note : My first table is in SQL server and 2nd one is in Excel File

Comment: Please share your current SQL query

Comment: I have resolved the issue by taking  left join with office postalcodes and filter out offices = Null

Comment: Great! Could you please share the solution as Answer to this question so that it will be helpful for the SO community.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue by taking Right join with office postalcodes and filter out offices = Null

*Step 1* Right Join

You can also use left join depending on the Master Table. My Master table is in right thats why i take right join
[image: Right Join]

*Step 2* Filter Where Office = Null

Put office field (or the field where postal code is located) on filter shelf and select 'NULL' only